# Where can I find the list view for queues

Tags: error, object, queue

I am trying to create a package for migration. I am getting the error:

> "**ListView - LiveChatTranscript.Queue1_LiveChatTranscript - The
>   queue queue1 has not been setup to support the object:
>   LiveChatTranscript. This must be configured in the setup UI Queues
>   editor.**"

I checked the queue and it does have "Chat Transcript" selected as the supported object. Now I am thinking the error lies in some List View created, but I have no idea where to find and modify that list view. Can someone please help where exactly  I need to go in Setup?

Comment: also, I have 2 other queues and they work just fine.

Comment: I found this as well https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3DIAA0&title=global-list-view-created-as-part-of-queue-creation-has-empty-developer-name-unique-name, but I am confused where he says "go to one of the supported objects tab and then select the list created." Where exactly do I need to go?